# Import Textures in roomle

Tags: roomle

is it possible to add his own floor textures? Because the software itself is pretty good but I need this feature. I already tried other programs, but no one had this feature.
Regards Rimser

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to add custom floor textures in the Rubens configurator but it's not possible in the floor planner.